# R - create tomography plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph:

```
set.seed(123456)
test1_1 <- round(rnorm(20,mean=40,sd=5),0)/100
test1_2 <- round(rnorm(20,mean=60,sd=5),0)/100
test.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(test1_1,test1_2))
test <- ggplot(test.data, aes(test1_1,test1_2))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +   # OP missing `+`
  abline(0.5,0.5)
test
```

Now I have point, which are created with the following formular:

```
line <- function(beta_2, test1_1,test1_2){
beta_1 = (test1_2/(1-test1_1))-(test1_1/(1-test1_1))*beta_2
return(beta_1)}


  output1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,20,1))
  beta_2 <- 1
  for (i in 1:nrow(test.data)){
    output1[i,] <- line(beta_2,test.data[i,1],test.data[i,2])
  }

  output2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,20,1))
  beta_2 <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(ei.data)){
    output2[i,] <- line(beta_2,test.data[i,1],test.data[i,2])
  }

  output <- cbind(output1,output2)
```

I would like the add the data in the second data frame as lines in the plot created above (always connect the points per one row). However, using

```
abline(output[1,1],output[1,2])
```

does not work. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

abline() is syntax for base R, for ggplot2 you need to use geom_abline(output[1,1],output[1,2])

```
ggplot(test.data, aes(test1_1,test1_2)) + 
geom_point()+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
geom_abline(slope = output[1,1],intercept = output[1,2])
```

Note: Your reproducible had an error in which ei.data was used instead of test.data, and part of your ggplot call was missing a + sign, I only point this out so others (or you) do not get caught in a separate error without realizing it.